# How to rotate a whole SVG text object instead of the individual glyphs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to develop a game based in the "Circle of fifths" which is a musical concept. To make it correct, I've rotated elements by 15 degrees so that the very top of the circle is halfway through the first segment, rather than the start of the first segment (you could argue that it's rotated by -15 degrees but whatever).

The issue I am now facing is that the I cannot rotate text inside my circle segments as required. Each segment is a `<g>` element with a child `<path>` and a child `<text>` element nested within. At the moment, I am just using the `rotate` attribute and this is ok for a single character or maybe 2 characters, but anymore than that and it looks incorrect. The `rotate` attribute is working as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) ("Rotates orientation of each individual glyph. Can rotate glyphs individually."). I would like to rotate the entire `<text>` element so that all the characters are rotated to the same angle **AND** appear to be rendered on the same line, perpendicular to the rotation of the letters.

I have attempted to use combinations of `transform=rotate(15)` and `text-anchor: middle` instead of using the `rotate` attribute but it looks as if it moves the element in the X and Y coordinates as well. I have also tried using the `dominant-baseline` attribute but my VSCode states that the property doesn't exist and the `glyph-orientation-horizontal` attribute, which just didn't do anything as far as I could tell.

Here is my code (I'm using Reactjs, so I'm just giving you the component code that can just be put into an App.js very easily and the component's CSS code (there are a couple lines of D3 btw, just to calculate path arcs)) as well as some screenshots, one image without using the `rotate` attribute and the other does use the `rotate` attribute.

Component and CSS code:

```js
// My component
import './CircleOfFifths.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import musicKeys from '../../MusicKeys';

export default function CircleOfFifths({ outerRadius }) {

  const diameter = outerRadius * 2;
  const innerRadius = outerRadius * 0.7;
  const innerRadius2 = outerRadius * 0.4;

  const [musicKeysObject, setMusicKeysObject] = useState(musicKeys);

  useEffect(() => {
    let newMusicKeysObject = musicKeysObject;
    for (let i=0; i<newMusicKeysObject.length; i++) {
      newMusicKeysObject[i].segmentMetadata.majorCircle.isVisible = true;
      newMusicKeysObject[i].segmentMetadata.minorCircle.isVisible = true;
    }
    setMusicKeysObject([...newMusicKeysObject]);
  }, [])

  const majorOnMouseUpHandler = (index) => {
    let newMusicKeysObject = musicKeysObject;
    if (newMusicKeysObject[index].segmentMetadata.majorCircle.isVisible) {
      newMusicKeysObject[index].segmentMetadata.majorCircle.isVisible = false;
    } else {
      newMusicKeysObject[index].segmentMetadata.majorCircle.isVisible = true;
    }
    setMusicKeysObject([...newMusicKeysObject]);
  }

  const minorOnMouseUpHandler = (index) => {
    let newMusicKeysObject = musicKeysObject;
    if (newMusicKeysObject[index].segmentMetadata.minorCircle.isVisible) {
      newMusicKeysObject[index].segmentMetadata.minorCircle.isVisible = false;
    } else {
      newMusicKeysObject[index].segmentMetadata.minorCircle.isVisible = true;
    }
    setMusicKeysObject([...newMusicKeysObject]);
  }

  const calculateArc = (innerRadius, outerRadius, startAngle, endAngle) => {
    return d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius)
      .startAngle(startAngle)
      .endAngle(endAngle);
  }

  const renderMajorSegment = (musicKey, index) => {
    let arc = calculateArc(outerRadius, innerRadius, musicKey.segmentMetadata.startAngle, musicKey.segmentMetadata.endAngle);
    let [arcCenterX, arcCenterY] = arc.centroid();

    return <g className={`circle-segment ${musicKey.segmentMetadata.majorCircle.isVisible ? 'isVisible': ''}`} key={index} onMouseUp={() => majorOnMouseUpHandler(index)}>
            <path 
              d={arc.apply()} // apply() is needed to generate the string that goes into the 'd' attribute
            />
            {/* Need to adjust center X position due to increased font-size */}
            <text x={arcCenterX-10} y={arcCenterY} rotate={15}>
              {musicKey.chords[0].replace('Major', '')}
            </text>
          </g>
  }

  const renderMinorSegment = (musicKey, index) => {
    let arc = calculateArc(innerRadius, innerRadius2, musicKey.segmentMetadata.startAngle, musicKey.segmentMetadata.endAngle);
    let [arcCenterX, arcCenterY] = arc.centroid();

    return <g className={`circle-segment ${musicKey.segmentMetadata.minorCircle.isVisible ? 'isVisible': ''}`} key={index} onMouseUp={() => minorOnMouseUpHandler(index)}>
            <path 
              d={arc.apply()} // apply() is needed to generate the string that goes into the 'd' attribute
            />
            {/* Need to adjust center X position due to increased font-size */}
            <text x={arcCenterX-10} y={arcCenterY} rotate={15}>
              {musicKey.chords[5].replace(' minor', 'mgh')}
            </text>
          </g>
  }

  return (
    <div className='circle-of-fifths-container'>
      <svg
        height={diameter*1.1}
        width={diameter*1.1}>
        <g className='circle-container' transform={`translate(${diameter/2 + 25},${diameter/2 + 25}) rotate(-15)`}>
          <circle r={outerRadius} className="base-circle"/>
          <g className='outer-circle-segments-container'>
            {musicKeysObject.map((musicKey, index) => renderMajorSegment(musicKey, index))}
          </g>
          <g className='inner-circle-segments-container'>
            {musicKeysObject.map((musicKey, index) => renderMinorSegment(musicKey, index))}
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  )
}

// It's CSS
.circle-of-fifths-container {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.base-circle {
  fill: grey;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

.circle-segment {
  visibility: none;
}

.circle-segment.isVisible {
  visibility: visible;
  > path {
    fill: #D7DCDF;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 5px;
  }
  > text {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-anchor: initial;
  }
}
```

[image: The rendering without using the rotate attribute]
[image: The rendering using the rotate attribute]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s review (a) how objects are rotated in SVG and (b) how text is positioned in SVG. We start with a simple square:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <rect x="15" y="15" width="30" height="30"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

Now we’ll rotate this using `transform=rotate(45)`:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <rect x="15" y="15" width="30" height="30" transform="rotate(45)"/>
</svg>
```

[image]
[image]

The square has rotated, but around the **origin** point – coordinate (0,0) – which in this case is the top left corner of the viewbox. Rotations in SVG, by default, are performed around the origin point. If we want to rotate an object around any other point, we need to specify those coordinates as the second and third parameters to the [rotate transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#rotate). We want to rotate around the centre of the square, which is at the point (30,30), so our transform needs to be `transform=rotate(45, 30, 30)`.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <rect x="15" y="15" width="30" height="30" transform="rotate(45, 30, 30)"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

Okay, magic! That’s what we want! Now let’s try some text, and we’ll position it at the centre of our viewport (30,30).

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <text x="30" y="30">fred</text>
</svg>
```

[image]

So, by default, the x coordinate specifies the **start** of the text and the y coordinate specifies its **baseline**. That’s not what we want. We want both coordinates to specify the **centre** of the text. We can do this by setting `text-anchor="middle"` for the horizontal alignment and `dominant-baseline="central"` for the vertical alignment.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <text x="30" y="30" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">fred</text>
</svg>
```

[image]

Yes! Now it’s a simple matter to rotate around (30,30) to achieve the desired result.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <text x="30" y="30" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" transform="rotate(45, 30, 30)">fred</text>
</svg>
```

[image]
[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
  background: #f6f6f6
}
svg {
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <text x="30" y="30" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" transform="rotate(45, 30, 30)">fred</text>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <text x="30" y="30" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
    <animateTransform id="op"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 30 30"
      to="360 30 30"
      dur="1s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
    fred
  </text>
</svg>
```

So now, hopefully, you can take these SVG concepts and implement them within your React code.

---

Note 1. SVG viewboxes don’t necessarily have the origin point in the top left corner. You can set up a viewbox so that
(0,0) is in the centre, for example:

```
<svg viewBox="-30 -30 60 60">
```

---

Note 2. SVG transforms can be also animated. See the snippet above for an example, and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform) is a decent place to start for documentation.

Comment: Thank you! This is really great, informative and well put together answer. My only issue is using the `dominant-baseline` attribute. As I said in my question, my VSCode states that it is an "unknown property" and with some googling, I've found a [page](https://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/dominant-baseline.php) stating that it is deprecated. There are also some [Github issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/issues/215) opened by others with the same issue. How would you recommend avoiding this? Just adding the CSS property to my VSCode, even though its deprecated?

Comment: I've just put the property in my CSS file and it appears to work as expected. My guess it still works in the browser, VSCode is just "unaware" that the property exists for whatever reason. Thank you again! Your answer was really clear and informative!

Comment: The [SVG2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#DominantBaselineProperty) spec does not say that `dominant-baseline` is deprecated; neither does the [CSS3 Inline Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#propdef-dominant-baseline) spec. These specs are both still in draft status, though, so not yet set in stone, but if you find it works in the major browsers I see no reason to avoid it.

Comment: Just read the issue you linked to in VSCode’s Github repo. The issue was raised by someone who discovered, like you, that VSCode doesn't recognise the property. Microsoft closed the issue with this comment: “the outcome was not to include SVG support in the core as most people don't hand-write SVG.” That’s hilarious, but asinine.

Comment: Yes it seems like a very stupid outcome for that issue, I believe enough people would want to use to make it something that should be included, but hey, you can still use it and see it works as expected when rendering things in the browser so I'm not really fussed.