# Rotating SVG children on their own axis

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG element with child elements such as text/circle.  The svg element represents a soccer field as shown below.  Currently it is sitting upright.

**UPRIGHT SVG**

[image]

What I want to do is also have it rotate 90 to the right as shown below:

**ROTATED SVG**

[image]

**PROBLEM** The issue I am facing is I cant rotate the text to show upright, because if i try to rotate that -90deg it rotates on the WHOLE axis of the main svg, pushing the text OUT.

How can I JUST rotate the main svg text element?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196903/2518285) help? Especially the part where I am rotating the word “fred” around its own centre. Basically whenever you do a rotation in SVG, you need to specify the point you want to rotate around. So if you're rotating just the letters GK, you need to rotate around the midpoint of those letters.

Comment: Thank you @BrettDonald. It definitely does.  I have another quick question, how can I fit an image on top of the circle, like a person's face?  I have tried almost everything.

Comment: @BrettDonald Really resourceful answer there!  Thank you :). But yes if you have any idea regarding the image inside the svg it would be awesome!

Comment: To "fit an image on top of a circle" I would use a clip path to make the image **appear as** a circle, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56113424/2518285).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate a whole SVG text object instead of the individual glyphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76196079/how-to-rotate-a-whole-svg-text-object-instead-of-the-individual-glyphs)

Comment: @Eddsters open a new question with the issue with the circle/image

Comment: @chrwahl I have resolved this. It can be done simply using CSS